# Copy Qt kit settings to another computer

Tags: xml, import, export, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I have a bash script to download the tarballs with sysroot and crosscompilation toolchain from remote server to a linux computer (we are using Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Debian, mint etc. for various reasons) and decompress them in a certain path. The paths to the sysroot and toolchain will ALWAYS be the same (there are some symlinks with absolute paths, legacy of buildroot. We consider it to not be an isssue pressing enough to change that).

Now I thought why do not have, as part of the same script, some feature to set the QtCreator kit as well. It would help me greatly.

As I have not found any usefull hints as how to do so (without completely rewriting the current settings, i only wish to append a new kit and not delete anything the user might already have set) i have located the *~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/profiles.xml* and tried to simply "copy" the kit definition (and increase thi Profile.Count by 1). However the file got rewritten to it's original state after each Qmaker start... I tried to delete the ~/.cashe, which had the effect that renaming a kit (profile) in the XML worked, but adding a new kit still does not. Now I admit I have no idea what am I doing, and I am unsure whether this could work at all, given there are some hashes in the XML file (such as     `<value type="QString" key="PE.Profile.Device">{8a289892-2c6c-4588-9ad5-f835b487c0ca}</value>)`, but I figured it should be all right as long as I keep all the hashes in all xml files (profiles.xml, devices.xml etc.) consistent and I will stop the script when duplicity is found).

Is there any better way to import/export kit (and compiler) setting to another computer?
Is this the way and I am missing something obvious?

Comment: Two things to check:
* The profiles.xml does reference other .xml files in the same folder such as qtversion.xml, toolchains.xml, so you might have to copy their content as well
* In the profiles.xml each profile has a key "PE.Profile.AutoDetected". If that one is "true", qtcreator is free to remove them on startup if it does not find that Kit automatically again.

Comment: I am pretty sure the autodetect was OFF. My friend has managed to use my original approach to write a script which worked on his computer but not on mine (mine: Ubuntu 18.04, QtCreator 4.11.1, his was clean install with 22.04 and new Qt as well). So right now we are able to transfer the kit from mine computer to a clean one (which seems to indicate that the refferences to other XMLs are indeed the issue). Although not ideal solution it works for us (for now, anyway).